# THREE.JS | GLSL Set particle colour by scene texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, textures, particles

I have matrix of GLSL particles (THREE.Points), which have to be coloured by overall scene texture.

[image]

So, the result should be like this:

[image]

Yeah, I can create canvas and set buffer.color by ctx.getImageData(left, top, width, height), but is it possible to set it inside shader?

I have tried to get particle 'global' position, but without any success.

The output is:

[image]

```js
    
var blob = "data:image/png;base64,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";
      
var pattern = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QVURXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAAABAgAAAAEBAAMAAAABAgAAAAECAAMAAAADAAAAngEGAAMAAAABAAIAAAESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEVAAMAAAABAAMAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAApAEbAAUAAAABAAAArAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAfAAAAtAEyAAIAAAAUAAAA04dpAAQAAAABAAAA6AAAASAACAAIAAgACvyAAAAnEAAK/IAAACcQQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIChNYWNpbnRvc2gpADIwMjA6MDU6MDEgMTI6NDQ6MjUAAAAEkAAABwAAAAQwMjIxoAEAAwAAAAH//wAAoAIABAAAAAEAAACAoAMABAAAAAEAAACAAAAAAAAAAAYBAwADAAAAAQAGAAABGgAFAAAAAQAAAW4BGwAFAAAAAQAAAXYBKAADAAAAAQACAAACAQAEAAAAAQAAAX4CAgAEAAAAAQAAA84AAAAAAAAASAAAAAEAAABIAAAAAf/Y/+0ADEFkb2JlX0NNAAH/7gAOQWRvYmUAZIAAAAAB/9sAhAAMCAgICQgMCQkMEQsKCxEVDwwMDxUYExMVExMYEQwMDAwMDBEMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMAQ0LCw0ODRAODhAUDg4OFBQODg4OFBEMDAwMDBERDAwMDAwMEQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCACAAIADASIAAhEBAxEB/90ABAAI/8QBPwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAwABAgQFBgcICQoLAQABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAABAAIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAEEAQMCBAIFBwYIBQMMMwEAAhEDBCESMQVBUWETInGBMgYUkaGxQiMkFVLBYjM0coLRQwclklPw4fFjczUWorKDJkSTVGRFwqN0NhfSVeJl8rOEw9N14/NGJ5SkhbSVxNTk9KW1xdXl9VZmdoaWprbG1ub2N0dXZ3eHl6e3x9fn9xEAAgIBAgQEAwQFBgcHBgU1AQACEQMhMRIEQVFhcSITBTKBkRShsUIjwVLR8DMkYuFygpJDUxVjczTxJQYWorKDByY1wtJEk1SjF2RFVTZ0ZeLys4TD03Xj80aUpIW0lcTU5PSltcXV5fVWZnaGlqa2xtbm9ic3R1dnd4eXp7fH/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwCgkkku0fQlJJJJKexHCSQ4SWM/NykkkkFOYkkkvMW6pMeE6Y8JKfMTyUyc8lMvoF7UKSSSRS//0KCSSS7R9CUkkkkp7EcJJhwnWK/NykkkklOYkkkvMW6pMeE6Y8JKfMTyUyc8lMvoF7VSSSSKX//R8+SSSXpzTUnHITJxyEEPpw4TphwnXz88UpJJJJTppJJL05pKTHhOkeElPHJJJLafpFSSSSSn/9Lz5JJJenNNScchMnHIQQ+nDhOmHCdfPzxSkkkklOmkkkvTmkpI8JJjwkp49JJJbT9IqSSSSU//06CSSS7R9CUkkkkp7AcJ0hwksV+blJJJJKcxJJJeYt1SY8J0x4SU+Ynkpk55KZfQL2qkkkkUv//UoJJJLtH0JSSSSSnsRwkmHCdYr83KSSSSU5iSSS8xbqkx4Tpjwkp8xPJTJzyUy+gXtVJJJIpf/9Xz5JJJenNNScchMnHIQQ+nDhOmHCdfPzxSkkkklOmkkkvTmkpMeE6R4SU8ckkktp+kVJJJJKf/1vPkkkl6c01JxyEycchBBfThwnTDhOvn54pSSSSSnTSSSXpzSUkeEkjwip45JJJbL9IqSSSSU//Z/+0NElBob3Rvc2hvcCAzLjAAOEJJTQQEAAAAAAAHHAIAAAIAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDo8VzzL8EYoaJ7Z63FZNW6OEJJTQQ6AAAAAAEVAAAAEAAAAAEAAAAAAAtwcmludE91dHB1dAAAAAUAAAAAUHN0U2Jvb2wBAAAAAEludGVlbnVtAAAAAEludGUAAAAASW1nIAAAAA9wcmludFNpeHRlZW5CaXRib29sAAAAAAtwcmludGVyTmFtZVRFWFQAAAAZAEIAcgBvAHQAaABlAHIAIABIAEwALQA1ADIANQAwAEQATgAgAHMAZQByAGkAZQBzAAAAAAAPcHJpbnRQcm9vZlNldHVwT2JqYwAAAAwAUAByAG8AbwBmACAAUwBlAHQAdQBwAAAAAAAKcHJvb2ZTZXR1cAAAAAEAAAAAQmx0bmVudW0AAAAMYnVpbHRpblByb29mAAAACXByb29mQ01ZSwA4QklNBDsAAAAAAi0AAAAQAAAAAQAAAAAAEnByaW50T3V0cHV0T3B0aW9ucwAAABcAAAAAQ3B0bmJvb2wAAAAAAENsYnJib29sAAAAAABSZ3NNYm9vbAAAAAAAQ3JuQ2Jvb2wAAAAAAENudENib29sAAAAAABMYmxzYm9vbAAAAAAATmd0dmJvb2wAAAAAAEVtbERib29sAAAAAABJbnRyYm9vbAAAAAAAQmNrZ09iamMAAAABAAAAAAAAUkdCQwAAAAMAAAAAUmQgIGRvdWJAb+AAAAAAAAAAAABHcm4gZG91YkBv4AAAAAAAAAAAAEJsICBkb3ViQG/gAAAAAAAAAAAAQnJkVFVudEYjUmx0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQmxkIFVudEYjUmx0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUnNsdFVudEYjUHhsQFIAAAAAAAAAAAAKdmVjdG9yRGF0YWJvb2wBAAAAAFBnUHNlbnVtAAAAAFBnUHMAAAAAUGdQQwAAAABMZWZ0VW50RiNSbHQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABUb3AgVW50RiNSbHQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABTY2wgVW50RiNQcmNAWQAAAAAAAAAAABBjcm9wV2hlblByaW50aW5nYm9vbAAAAAAOY3JvcFJlY3RCb3R0b21sb25nAAAAAAAAAAxjcm9wUmVjdExlZnRsb25nAAAAAAAAAA1jcm9wUmVjdFJpZ2h0bG9uZwAAAAAAAAALY3JvcFJlY3RUb3Bsb25nAAAAAAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEAAgBIAAAAAQACOEJJTQQmAAAAAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAD+AAAA4QklNA/IAAAAAAAoAAP///////wAAOEJJTQQNAAAAAAAEAAAAWjhCSU0EGQAAAAAABAAAAB44QklNA/MAAAAAAAkAAAAAAAAAAAEAOEJJTScQAAAAAAAKAAEAAAAAAAAAAjhCSU0D9QAAAAAASAAvZmYAAQBsZmYABgAAAAAAAQAvZmYAAQChmZoABgAAAAAAAQAyAAAAAQBaAAAABgAAAAAAAQA1AAAAAQAtAAAABgAAAAAAAThCSU0D+AAAAAAAcAAA/////////////////////////////wPoAAAAAP////////////////////////////8D6AAAAAD/////////////////////////////A+gAAAAA/////////////////////////////wPoAAA4QklNBAgAAAAAABAAAAABAAACQAAAAkAAAAAAOEJJTQQeAAAAAAAEAAAAADhCSU0EGgAAAAADQwAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAACAAAAABwBwAGEAdAB0AGUAcgBuAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAABAAAAAAAAbnVsbAAAAAIAAAAGYm91bmRzT2JqYwAAAAEAAAAAAABSY3QxAAAABAAAAABUb3AgbG9uZwAAAAAAAAAATGVmdGxvbmcAAAAAAAAAAEJ0b21sb25nAAAAgAAAAABSZ2h0bG9uZwAAAIAAAAAGc2xpY2VzVmxMcwAAAAFPYmpjAAAAAQAAAAAABXNsaWNlAAAAEgAAAAdzbGljZUlEbG9uZwAAAAAAAAAHZ3JvdXBJRGxvbmcAAAAAAAAABm9yaWdpbmVudW0AAAAMRVNsaWNlT3JpZ2luAAAADWF1dG9HZW5lcmF0ZWQAAAAAVHlwZWVudW0AAAAKRVNsaWNlVHlwZQAAAABJbWcgAAAABmJvdW5kc09iamMAAAABAAAAAAAAUmN0MQAAAAQAAAAAVG9wIGxvbmcAAAAAAAAAAExlZnRsb25nAAAAAAAAAABCdG9tbG9uZwAAAIAAAAAAUmdodGxvbmcAAACAAAAAA3VybFRFWFQAAAABAAAAAAAAbnVsbFRFWFQAAAABAAAAAAAATXNnZVRFWFQAAAABAAAAAAAGYWx0VGFnVEVYVAAAAAEAAAAAAA5jZWxsVGV4dElzSFRNTGJvb2wBAAAACGNlbGxUZXh0VEVYVAAAAAEAAAAAAAlob3J6QWxpZ25lbnVtAAAAD0VTbGljZUhvcnpBbGlnbgAAAAdkZWZhdWx0AAAACXZlcnRBbGlnbmVudW0AAAAPRVNsaWNlVmVydEFsaWduAAAAB2RlZmF1bHQAAAALYmdDb2xvclR5cGVlbnVtAAAAEUVTbGljZUJHQ29sb3JUeXBlAAAAAE5vbmUAAAAJdG9wT3V0c2V0bG9uZwAAAAAAAAAKbGVmdE91dHNldGxvbmcAAAAAAAAADGJvdHRvbU91dHNldGxvbmcAAAAAAAAAC3JpZ2h0T3V0c2V0bG9uZwAAAAAAOEJJTQQoAAAAAAAMAAAAAj/wAAAAAAAAOEJJTQQUAAAAAAAEAAAADThCSU0EDAAAAAAD6gAAAAEAAACAAAAAgAAAAYAAAMAAAAADzgAYAAH/2P/tAAxBZG9iZV9DTQAB/+4ADkFkb2JlAGSAAAAAAf/bAIQADAgICAkIDAkJDBELCgsRFQ8MDA8VGBMTFRMTGBEMDAwMDAwRDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAENCwsNDg0QDg4QFA4ODhQUDg4ODhQRDAwMDAwREQwMDAwMDBEMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM/8AAEQgAgACAAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/dAAQACP/EAT8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAMAAQIEBQYHCAkKCwEAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAQACAwQFBgcICQoLEAABBAEDAgQCBQcGCAUDDDMBAAIRAwQhEjEFQVFhEyJxgTIGFJGhsUIjJBVSwWIzNHKC0UMHJZJT8OHxY3M1FqKygyZEk1RkRcKjdDYX0lXiZfKzhMPTdePzRieUpIW0lcTU5PSltcXV5fVWZnaGlqa2xtbm9jdHV2d3h5ent8fX5/cRAAICAQIEBAMEBQYHBwYFNQEAAhEDITESBEFRYXEiEwUygZEUobFCI8FS0fAzJGLhcoKSQ1MVY3M08SUGFqKygwcmNcLSRJNUoxdkRVU2dGXi8rOEw9N14/NGlKSFtJXE1OT0pbXF1eX1VmZ2hpamtsbW5vYnN0dXZ3eHl6e3x//aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AoJJJLtH0JSSSSSnsRwkkOEljPzcpJJJBTmJJJLzFuqTHhOmPCSnzE8lMnPJTL6Be1CkkkkUv/9Cgkkku0fQlJJJJKexHCSYcJ1ivzcpJJJJTmJJJLzFuqTHhOmPCSnzE8lMnPJTL6Be1Ukkkil//0fPkkkl6c01JxyEycchBD6cOE6YcJ18/PFKSSSSU6aSSS9OaSkx4TpHhJTxySSS2n6RUkkkkp//S8+SSSXpzTUnHITJxyEEPpw4TphwnXz88UpJJJJTppJJL05pKSPCSY8JKePSSSW0/SKkkkklP/9Ogkkku0fQlJJJJKewHCdIcJLFfm5SSSSSnMSSSXmLdUmPCdMeElPmJ5KZOeSmX0C9qpJJJFL//1KCSSS7R9CUkkkkp7EcJJhwnWK/NykkkklOYkkkvMW6pMeE6Y8JKfMTyUyc8lMvoF7VSSSSKX//V8+SSSXpzTUnHITJxyEEPpw4TphwnXz88UpJJJJTppJJL05pKTHhOkeElPHJJJLafpFSSSSSn/9bz5JJJenNNScchMnHIQQX04cJ0w4Tr5+eKUkkkkp00kkl6c0lJHhJI8IqeOSSSWy/SKkkkklP/2ThCSU0EIQAAAAAAUwAAAAEBAAAADwBBAGQAbwBiAGUAIABQAGgAbwB0AG8AcwBoAG8AcAAAABIAQQBkAG8AYgBlACAAUABoAG8AdABvAHMAaABvAHAAIABDAEMAAAABADhCSU0EBgAAAAAABwAHAQEAAQEA/+EO/2h0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8APD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSLvu78iIGlkPSJXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6TlRjemtjOWQiPz4gPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iQWRvYmUgWE1QIENvcmUgNS42LWMxNDAgNzkuMTYwNDUxLCAyMDE3LzA1LzA2LTAxOjA4OjIxICAgICAgICAiPiA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPiA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtbG5zOnhtcE1NPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvbW0vIiB4bWxuczpzdEV2dD0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL3NUeXBlL1Jlc291cmNlRXZlbnQjIiB4bWxuczpkYz0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2VsZW1lbnRzLzEuMS8iIHhtbG5zOnBob3Rvc2hvcD0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS9waG90b3Nob3AvMS4wLyIgeG1wOkNyZWF0b3JUb29sPSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ0MgKE1hY2ludG9zaCkiIHhtcDpDcmVhdGVEYXRlPSIyMDIwLTA1LTAxVDEyOjIyOjA5KzAzOjAwIiB4bXA6TWV0YWRhdGFEYXRlPSIyMDIwLTA1LTAxVDEyOjQ0OjI1KzAzOjAwIiB4bXA6TW9kaWZ5RGF0ZT0iMjAyMC0wNS0wMVQxMjo0NDoyNSswMzowMCIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDoxMDE1YTk5Yy02MDFhLTQ4ZTYtYmZjYy1lZjFmZDQ1MDA3YTAiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9ImFkb2JlOmRvY2lkOnBob3Rvc2hvcDo5NjU5MzU1MC1mNGVhLTAyNGUtOWM1YS0zMmNiYjNjMmQwZmYiIHhtcE1NOk9yaWdpbmFsRG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDowMzM0N2QzZi1iZTA0LTQxNTQtODBlMS00ZWVhNDVmMTM0MDQiIGRjOmZvcm1hdD0iaW1hZ2UvanBlZyIgcGhvdG9zaG9wOkxlZ2FjeUlQVENEaWdlc3Q9IjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAxIiBwaG90b3Nob3A6Q29sb3JNb2RlPSIzIiBwaG90b3Nob3A6SUNDUHJvZmlsZT0iRGlzcGxheSBQMyI+IDx4bXBNTTpIaXN0b3J5PiA8cmRmOlNlcT4gPHJkZjpsaSBzdEV2dDphY3Rpb249ImNyZWF0ZWQiIHN0RXZ0Omluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6MDMzNDdkM2YtYmUwNC00MTU0LTgwZTEtNGVlYTQ1ZjEzNDA0IiBzdEV2dDp3aGVuPSIyMDIwLTA1LTAxVDEyOjIyOjA5KzAzOjAwIiBzdEV2dDpzb2Z0d2FyZUFnZW50PSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ0MgKE1hY2ludG9zaCkiLz4gPHJkZjpsaSBzdEV2dDphY3Rpb249InNhdmVkIiBzdEV2dDppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjc3MDM5N2M0LTI3YTItNDM4ZS05MzZiLTAwMzA2MTA2YjAwMSIgc3RFdnQ6d2hlbj0iMjAyMC0wNS0wMVQxMjoyMjowOSswMzowMCIgc3RFdnQ6c29mdHdhcmVBZ2VudD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIiBzdEV2dDpjaGFuZ2VkPSIvIi8+IDxyZGY6bGkgc3RFdnQ6YWN0aW9uPSJzYXZlZCIgc3RFdnQ6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDoxMDE1YTk5Yy02MDFhLTQ4ZTYtYmZjYy1lZjFmZDQ1MDA3YTAiIHN0RXZ0OndoZW49IjIwMjAtMDUtMDFUMTI6NDQ6MjUrMDM6MDAiIHN0RXZ0OnNvZnR3YXJlQWdlbnQ9IkFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgc3RFdnQ6Y2hhbmdlZD0iLyIvPiA8L3JkZjpTZXE+IDwveG1wTU06SGlzdG9yeT4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0idyI/Pv/iAjRJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAAiRhcHBsBAAAAG1udHJSR0IgWFlaIAfhAAcABwANABYAIGFjc3BBUFBMAAAAAEFQUEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD21gABAAAAANMtYXBwbMoalYIlfxBNOJkT1dHqFYIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACmRlc2MAAAD8AAAAZWNwcnQAAAFkAAAAI3d0cHQAAAGIAAAAFHJYWVoAAAGcAAAAFGdYWVoAAAGwAAAAFGJYWVoAAAHEAAAAFHJUUkMAAAHYAAAAIGNoYWQAAAH4AAAALGJUUkMAAAHYAAAAIGdUUkMAAAHYAAAAIGRlc2MAAAAAAAAAC0Rpc3BsYXkgUDMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAdGV4dAAAAABDb3B5cmlnaHQgQXBwbGUgSW5jLiwgMjAxNwAAWFlaIAAAAAAAAPNRAAEAAAABFsxYWVogAAAAAAAAg98AAD2/////u1hZWiAAAAAAAABKvwAAsTcAAAq5WFlaIAAAAAAAACg4AAARCwAAyLlwYXJhAAAAAAADAAAAAmZmAADypwAADVkAABPQAAAKW3NmMzIAAAAAAAEMQgAABd7///MmAAAHkwAA/ZD///ui///9owAAA9wAAMBu/+4AIUFkb2JlAGRAAAAAAQMAEAMCAwYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2wCEAAEBAQEBAQEBAQECAQEBAgIBAQEBAgICAgICAgIDAgMDAwMCAwMEBAQEBAMFBQUFBQUHBwcHBwgICAgICAgICAgBAQEBAgICBAMDBAcFBAUHCAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICP/CABEIAIAAgAMBEQACEQEDEQH/xACfAAEAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQMKAggBAQABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAQIECgsJCBAAAAQFBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAxASMwQUETEyEzQgBREAAQICCAUFAQAAAAAAAAAAAQACMgMQQXGRInKSMyAhMbGyUWFCUhMjEgABAQcFAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABADFxkbECMnIQIEEiA1EhQv/aAAwDAQECEQMRAAAA8lbUm6sB3bh6RvLbhkWW4giCvhjQV+n+YainLlwi9oPaopypQNMflXv9gd24ekby24ZFluIIgr4Y0Ffp/mGopy5cIvaD2qKcqUDTH5V7/YHduHpG8tuGRZbiCIK+GNBX6f5hqKcuXCL2g9qinKlA0v8Albv6gWW4mkjyu4Z1lmIIir4a0H/p2IqijKlwkdnzawpypAABdix7t+MHqn34sQmWnuXfg+YploK78vNv6o9zGu7LAzQeqWgUBdixbuuL5qr3YkQ6mp7n36vmCZ6Cu7Lzc+pPc34uzAMznqpoCAXYsW7ri+aq92JEOpqe59+r5gmegruy83PqT3N+LswDNB6paBQF2LHu34weqffixCZae5d+D5imWgrvy82/qj3Ma7ssAAWW4mkjyu4Z1lmIIir4a0H/AKdiKooypcJHZ82sKcqQDS/5W7+oHduHpG8tuGRZbiCIK+GNBX6f5hqKcuXCL2g9qinKlA0x+Ve/2B3bh6RvLbhkWW4giCvhjQV+n+YainLlwi9oPaopypQNL/lbv6gWW4mkjyu4Z1lmIIir4a0H/p2IqijKlwkdnzawpypAABdix7t+MHqn34sQmWnuXfg+YploK78vNv6o9zGu7LAzQeqWgUBdixbuuL5qr3YkQ6mp7n36vmCZ6Cu7Lzc+pPc34uzAMznqpoCAXYsW7ri+aq92JEOpqe59+r5gmegruy83PqT3N+LswDM56qaAgF2LFu64vmqvdiRDqanuffq+YJnoK7svNz6k9zfi7MA//9oACAECAAEFAIr2XvC5p3FSFjXsaH0vZe8LmncVIWNexofS9l7wuadxUhY17GhGQxIYkMLQcq7lvXJbGS2Li4bNt9hw3MdwY7gsrdwnrFZdE5CchOQkISEJCF8gui9uHCeyHBkOBh9w3Le3bNvGbGM2EWzeqFnLOYnMTn8X1C+rwt6ltTgjdG31fUL6vC3qW1OCN0bRnITkJyF8sui9t3Dex3BjuBhhwnLe4bJvJbGS2EXLeqEHLIYkMSGJzE5icwtZyrtm9cZsYzYuLdsm333CcyHBkOCyuHDesUF0SEJCEhfC9l7wuadxUhY17Gh9L2XvC5p3FSFjXsaEZDEhiQwtByruW9clsZLYuLhs232HDcx3BjuCyt3CesVl0TkJyE5CQhIQkIXyC6L24cJ7IcGQ4GH3Dct7ds28ZsYzYRbN6oWcs5icxOfxfUL6vC3qW1OCN0bfV9Qvq8LepbU4I3Rt9X1C+rwt6ltTgjdG0f/aAAgBAwABBQCP6Pn/AEPRAty2gzzZ4fX6Pn/Q9EC3LaDPNnh9fo+f9D0QLctoM82eEclsZLYyWxf3DZsfoEeRoY0MER6kZaakNSDJlOzbOSYzgxnBjODJcGS4MlwPXLkjxFPoQ0IGRaGZ66mNTH55nkWFu2bGM2MZsYzfw9we5wPY94fn+j87z/T3B7nA9j3h+f6PzvPHGcGM4MZwPWzkjxlPqQ1IGZaGR66GNDH55HkWFw2TGS2MlsZLYxmxjNjGbF/btkx+gZ5GpjUwRnqRFpoQ0IMkU7Ny5JkuDJcGS58fo+f9D0QLctoM82eH1+j5/wBD0QLctoM82eEclsZLYyWxf3DZsfoEeRoY0MER6kZaakNSDJlOzbOSYzgxnBjODJcGS4MlwPXLkjxFPoQ0IGRaGZ66mNTH55nkWFu2bGM2MZsYzfw9we5wPY94fn+j87z/AE9we5wPY94fn+j87z/T3B7nA9j3h+f6PzvPH//aAAgBAQABBQCLVVmlBXFXKFz57n0fTVVmlBXFXKFz57n0fTVVmlBXFXKFz57n0R7Wh2tDtaDLrRvMqT1TJEyQpSZVJVNKoSqFylWPctO5HU6Op0dTo7XR2ujtdFs67kWylY8yhMoJUqZKUyypEqQ8lPU800b3U0OpodTXxbei288E8k8YPUnav1bei288E8k8YPUnasep0dTo6nRbNO5FslWPKoSqCUqmSpMsyRMkPKT1POtE92tDtaHa0OpodTQ6mgy00TzKU9UqRKkKSmVSlTTKEyhcqVj3LruR2ujtdHa78NVWaUFcVcoXPnufR9NVWaUFcVcoXPnufRHtaHa0O1oMutG8ypPVMkTJClJlUlU0qhKoXKVY9y07kdTo6nR1OjtdHa6O10WzruRbKVjzKEyglSpkpTLKkSpDyU9TzTRvdTQ6mh1NfFt6LbzwTyTxg9Sdq/Vt6LbzwTyTxg9Sdq/Vt6LbzwTyTxg9Sdqx/9oACAECAgY/ANSjrU4qp5nrRkJqjES3lHWpxVTzPWjITVGIlvKOtTiqnmetGQmqMRLYxMTEfxHsIq4RVwiquwYeQqupaeCrTAq0wKo6lo4P1Ufv8iSampqYmJir/P5MlX2LTyfquMSrjEqnsWjkqnqGDgK0QVogh1EEP1NTU3ZXiZKvIz1peJqlw1CG+vEyVeRnrS8TVLhqENjU1NVf7/Jkq+paeD9VpgVaYFU9S0cFU9gwchXCKuEUOwih+JiYmJqamo/qPUQVogrRBVdQw8BVdi08lXGJVxiVR2LRyfqo/P5EkxMTNhR1qcVU8z1oyE1RiJbyjrU4qp5nrRkJqjES2MTExH8R7CKuEVcIqrsGHkKrqWngq0wKtMCqOpaOD9VH7/IkmpqamJiYq/z+TJV9i08n6rjEq4xKp7Fo5Kp6hg4CtEFaIIdRBD9TU1N2V4mSryM9aXiapcNQhvrxMlXkZ60vE1S4ahDfXiZKvIz1peJqlw1CGz//2gAIAQMCBj8A19MTJemRnvD0Hb/TEyXpkZ7w9B2/0xMl6ZGe8PQdsuEVcIq4RVfYWnkfF6ZGe8PQ6lnxWmCtMFaYK4xVxirjFHsWfUX7/PITVHUWjgfFaIK0QVohsLkX7/PITXniJby5F+/zyE154iWy0wVpgrTBHqWfEX7/ADyE1R2Fo5HxXCKuEVcIq0QVogrRBV9RaeB8XpkZ7w9DsWfVcYq4xVxjs9MTJemRnvD0Hb/TEyXpkZ7w9B2y4RVwirhFV9haeR8XpkZ7w9DqWfFaYK0wVpgrjFXGKuMUexZ9Rfv88hNUdRaOB8VogrRBWiGwuRfv88hNeeIlvLkX7/PITXniJby5F+/zyE154iWz/9oACAEBAQY/AKZeYd1LyjtS6wp1ppn5HeJU/O7yPHLzDupeUdqXWFOtNM/I7xKn53eR45eYd1LyjtS6wp1ppn5HeJU/O7yPBut1BbrdQW63UFKH6t5uaObh6qXiEIr9lEL1EL07EOhrCdhPU1FQm5Qm5T8JgdUfqVP/AJOjd8T9itp2kradpK2naSt12orddqK3XaipH9XRt+R+wUjEYG1n6hRG9RG9NxHqKym4R0FQUIuUIuUzCITV7Kafybzc48mj1W03SFtN0hbTdI4JGdvkFIyN8RS20JtgpmZT2UzMe/HIzt8gpGRviKW2hNsFMzKeymZj34Np2kradpK2naSpH8nRt+J+wUjCYG1H6hQm5Qm5NwnqKim4h0FYUQvUQvUzEITX7KaP1byc4cnD1W63UFut1BbrdQW03SFtN0hbTdIUo/k3k5p5tHqpeEQir2UIuUIuTsI6GoJ2I9TWVEb1Eb1PxGB1Z+pU/wDq6N3yP2K3Xait12orddqPBLzDupeUdqXWFOtNM/I7xKn53eR45eYd1LyjtS6wp1ppn5HeJU/O7yPBut1BbrdQW63UFKH6t5uaObh6qXiEIr9lEL1EL07EOhrCdhPU1FQm5Qm5T8JgdUfqVP8A5Ojd8T9itp2kradpK2naSt12orddqK3XaipH9XRt+R+wUjEYG1n6hRG9RG9NxHqKym4R0FQUIuUIuUzCITV7Kafybzc48mj1W03SFtN0hbTdI4JGdvkFIyN8RS20JtgpmZT2UzMe/HIzt8gpGRviKW2hNsFMzKeymZj345GdvkFIyN8RS20JtgpmZT2UzMe/B//Z";
    
var width = 512,
    height = 512;

inits();
    
function inits(){

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - 1, 1, 1, - 1, 0, 1 );
scene.add(camera);

var N = 8.0;
    
var points = [];
var colors = [];
    
for(var y = 16; y <= height - 16; y += N){
    for(var x = 16; x <= width - 16; x += N){
        
        var dx = -1.0 + x / width * 2;
        var dy = -1.0 + y / height * 2;

        points.push(new THREE.Vector2(dx, dy));
         
    }
}
    
buffer = {

    position: new Float32Array(points.length * 3),
    color: new Float32Array(points.length * 3),
    radius: new Float32Array(points.length * 1),

};
    
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    
    buffer.position[i * 3] = points[i].x;
    buffer.position[i * 3 + 1] = points[i].y;
    buffer.position[i * 3 + 2] = 0;
    
    buffer.radius[i] = N * 0.5;
    
    buffer.color[i * 3] = 1.0;
    buffer.color[i * 3 + 1] = 0.0;
    buffer.color[i * 3 + 2] = 1.0;
}
    
uniforms = { 
    
    blob: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(blob) },
    pattern: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(pattern) }
    
};

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    transparent: true
    
} );
    
material.extensions.fragDepth = true;
material.extensions.drawBuffers = true;

var cloud = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

cloud.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer.position, 3));
cloud.addAttribute('radius', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer.radius, 1));
cloud.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer.color, 3));
    
var points = new THREE.Points(cloud, material);
points.dynamic = true;
points.frustumCulled = false;

scene.add(points);
    
animate();
    
}

function animate() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PixelWordMap Demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="author" content="Vladimir V. KUCHINOV">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.js"></script>

    
</head>

<body>
    
<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertexShader'>

      uniform sampler2D blob;
      uniform sampler2D pattern;
      attribute float radius;
      attribute vec3 color;
      
      varying vec3 vColor;
      varying vec2 pos;
        
      void main() {
      
        vColor = color;
        
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_PointSize = radius;
        pos = vec2(1.0 + position.x / 2.0, 1.0 + position.y / 2.0);
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        
      }
      
</script>
    
<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragmentShader'>

      uniform sampler2D blob;
      uniform sampler2D pattern;
      varying vec3 vColor;
      varying vec2 pos;
      
      void main() {
      
          vec4 color = texture2D(pattern, vec2(pos.x, pos.y));
          gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(blob, gl_PointCoord);
          if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.1) discard; 
          
      }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The vertex shader output `varying vec2 pos;` is never assigned a value, because the position is assigned to the local variable `pos` with the same name: `vec2 pos = vec2(...);`. Change it to `pos = vec2(...);`.

Comment: Cheers, however it still creates glitchy output.

Answer (score 2):

The vertex shader output varying `vec2 pos;` is never assigned a value, because the position is assigned to the local variable `pos` with the same name: `vec2 pos = vec2(...);`.
Furthermore you missed the braces, to prioritized the `+` operation:

```c
pos = (position.xy + 1.0) / 2.0;
```

Choose a different number for `N to get a different` number of points:

```js
var N = 32;  
for(var y = N/2; y <= height; y += N){
    for(var x = N/2; x <= width; x += N){
        var dx = -1.0 + x / width * 2;
        var dy = -1.0 + y / height * 2;
        points.push(new THREE.Vector2(dx, dy));
    }
}
```

Note, the point size is limited. See [Working around gl_PointSize limitations in three.js / webGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371940/working-around-gl-pointsize-limitations-in-three-js-webgl).

```js
var blob = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAAMVWlDQ1BEaXNwbGF5AABIiZVXd1RTdxt+7khCQtiIgoywlyiiIENmmIKAbHARkgBhhHhJUHFbShWsW0RxVLQqYrXVCkgdiFpcxb3q+FCLo1KLA7fy/ZFAbf3O953vd8699z3P+7zPO+49OXkBvXUihaKA1AcK5UomISJEkJaeIeDcAwES2nCBi0hcrAiOj48BgL7n38/LKyAA4KKbSKEo+Nz/X4+BRFosBoh4AFmSYnEhQPwI0GViBaME2N4AbKcqFUqAPQGAMZOWngGwFQCMc9R2GQDjLLVdDcCYSUoQAuydgBZfJGJyAN0mAIIScY4S0L0GwF0ukckBPS0AAeJckQTQiwQwpLCwSALoKQE4ZX2ik/M3zax+TZEop99W9wIA0AqVFSsKRNP/z3H871NYoOrL4QCAn8tEJgAwBohr+UXRCQD4ANElz4qNA2AIEK9lEkBtk7xcVWSymk+ai4uFGQBMANJdIgqNBmAOkOHygtgYDZ6VLQuPAqAPkNNkyqgkTewCaXFYokZzHVOUENdnZzPCYE3sLhEDaPjHVPnJwRr9a7nSqD79F6W5SanqmileiSwlFoAuQJkU5ydGqzmUXWmuMLaPw6gSkgHYAZSvVB4RotanJmUz4QkaPlNY3NcvtSBXFhWrsdcqc5MiNTo7xaKwRACDAKpJKg9O7tORFqfF9PUikYaGqXunzknlyZp+qQ6FMiRBE/tMURCv4dM8aUFEAgAbgDYvLknUxNIBSiZJ847oWIUyPkldJ52VJxoTr66HnoYYCBEKAVQQIAtFyIOsvauxCwKNJxwiMMiBFG4apC8iFSIwkEOERJTiD8ghRXF/XAhEYCBFCeT40I+q727IhggMSiBFMfJxHwwKEY0CSKECAynk/dlS8BsYyD7LLkYRClAEBrL/gAVDiBgNourTFej1Mdlh7FB2JDuc7Uyb0QG0Hx1DB9BBdADtQXvTPn3V/sVn3WedZ91lXWZ1sK5Pls1n/tGPAGPRAZVmVlJkfdoz7UB70J50CO1PB9A+ENAmtBnc6JG0Nx1MB9J+tCftA6GmchU+1/5bD59MXcPjunNJ7kBuENfpn5G6Lrqe/SpSyP82IXWtWf1zFfZ7/plf+MmkJShC9D+Z1AJqL9VGHaFOUgeoRgiow1QTdYY6SDV+8hX9BgY5/dkSIIUc+SiA7LN8Ik1OBlIUu9e7P3J/r/YppdOUACAsUkxnZDm5SkGwQlEgFUTJxUOHCDzch/sAaekZAvXP1HMTEAAIk1N/YVNaAJ8KgMj5CxPZAvvvA0Yv/8JsnwH8pcDBc2IVU6LGaABggQc9GMMUlrCFE9zgAS/4IQhhGIM4JCEdkyBGLgrBYCpmYh7KUYmlWIW12IjN2I7vsAeNOIAj+BmncQ6XcQMd6MRjdOMl3hEEwSF0CCPClLAi7AlXwoPwJgKIMCKGSCDSiUwih5ATKmIm8QVRSSwn1hKbiDriB2I/cYQ4SZwnrhN3iEfEM+ItSZF80pi0IB3IYaQ3GUxGk0nkRDKHnEKWkmXkYrKarCV3kg3kEfI0eZnsIB+TPRQobcqEsqbcKG9KSMVRGVQ2xVCzqQqqiqqldlHNVBt1keqguqg3NJs2ogW0G+1HR9LJtJieQs+mF9Fr6e10A32MvkjfobvpjywdljnLleXLimKlsXJYU1nlrCrWVtY+1nHWZVYn6yWbzTZhO7JHsSPZ6ew89gz2IvZ69m52C/s8+x67h8PhmHJcOf6cOI6Io+SUc9ZwdnIOcy5wOjmvtbS1rLQ8tMK1MrTkWvO1qrR2aB3SuqD1QOsdV59rz/XlxnEl3OncJdwt3GbuWW4n9x3PgOfI8+cl8fJ483jVvF2847ybvOfa2to22j7a47Rl2nO1q7W/1z6hfUf7Dd+Q78IX8ifwVfzF/G38Fv51/nMdHR0HnSCdDB2lzmKdOp2jOrd1Xusa6Q7VjdKV6M7RrdFt0L2g+0SPq2evF6w3Sa9Ur0pvr95ZvS59rr6DvlBfpD9bv0Z/v/5V/R4DI4PhBnEGhQaLDHYYnDR4aMgxdDAMM5QYlhluNjxqeM+IMrI1EhqJjb4w2mJ03KjTmG3saBxlnGdcafydcbtx9wDDASMHpAyYNqBmwMEBHSaUiYNJlEmByRKTPSZXTN4OtBgYPFA6cOHAXQMvDHw1aPCgoEHSQRWDdg+6POitqcA0zDTfdJlpo+ktM9rMxWyc2VSzDWbHzboGGw/2GyweXDF4z+BfzUlzF/ME8xnmm83PmPdYWFpEWCgs1lgcteiyNLEMssyzXGl5yPKRlZFVgJXMaqXVYavfBQMEwYICQbXgmKDb2tw60lplvcm63fqdjaNNss18m902t2x5tt622bYrbVttu+2s7MbazbSrt/vVnmvvbZ9rv9q+zf6Vg6NDqsNXDo0ODx0HOUY5ljrWO9500nEKdJriVOt0yZnt7O2c77ze+ZwL6eLpkutS43LWlXT1cpW5rnc9P4Q1xGeIfEjtkKtufLdgtxK3erc7Q02GxgydP7Rx6JNhdsMyhi0b1jbso7une4H7Fvcbww2Hjxk+f3jz8GceLh5ijxqPSyN0RoSPmDOiacTTka4jpSM3jLzmaeQ51vMrz1bPD16jvBivXV6PRtmNyhy1btRVb2PveO9F3id8WD4hPnN8Dvi88fXyVfru8f3Tz80v32+H38PRjqOlo7eMvudv4y/y3+TfESAIyAz4JqAj0DpQFFgbeDfINkgStDXoQbBzcF7wzuAnIe4hTMi+kFdCX+EsYUsoFRoRWhHaHmYYlhy2Nux2uE14Tnh9eHeEZ8SMiJZIVmR05LLIq1EWUeKouqjuMaPGzBpzLJofnRi9NvpujEsME9M8lhw7ZuyKsTdj7WPlsY1xiIuKWxF3K94xfkr8T+PY4+LH1Yy7nzA8YWZCW6JR4uTEHYkvk0KSliTdSHZKViW3puilTEipS3mVGpq6PLUjbVjarLTT6WbpsvSmDE5GSsbWjJ7xYeNXje+c4DmhfMKViY4Tp008OclsUsGkg5P1Josm781kZaZm7sh8L4oT1Yp6sqKy1mV1i4Xi1eLHkiDJSskjqb90ufRBtn/28uyHOf45K3Ie5QbmVuV2yYSytbKneZF5G/Ne5cflb8vvLUgt2F2oVZhZuF9uKM+XHyuyLJpWdF7hqihXdEzxnbJqSjcTzWwtJoonFjcpjZUK5RmVk+pL1Z2SgJKaktdTU6bunWYwTT7tzHSX6QunPygNL/12Bj1DPKN1pvXMeTPvzAqetWk2MTtrdusc2zllczrnRszdPo83L3/eL/Pd5y+f/+KL1C+ayyzK5pbd+zLiy/py3XKm/OpXfl9tXEAvkC1oXzhi4ZqFHyskFacq3SurKt8vEi869fXwr6u/7l2cvbh9ideSDUvZS+VLrywLXLZ9ucHy0uX3Voxd0bBSsLJi5YtVk1edrBpZtXE1b7VqdUd1THXTGrs1S9e8X5u79nJNSM3udebrFq57tV6y/sKGoA27NlpsrNz49hvZN9c2RWxqqHWordrM3lyy+f6WlC1t33p/W7fVbGvl1g/b5Ns6tidsP1Y3qq5uh/mOJfVkvar+0c4JO899F/pd0y63XZt2m+yu/B7fq77//YfMH67sid7Tutd7764f7X9ct89oX0UD0TC9obsxt7GjKb3p/P4x+1ub/Zr3/TT0p20HrA/UHBxwcMkh3qGyQ72HSw/3tChauo7kHLnXOrn1xtG0o5eOjTvWfjz6+Imfw38+2hbcdviE/4kDJ31P7j/lfarxtNfphjOeZ/b94vnLvnav9oazo842nfM513x+9PlDFwIvHLkYevHnS1GXTl+OvXz+SvKVa1cnXO24Jrn28HrB9ae/lvz67sbcm6ybFbf0b1XdNr9d+y/nf+3u8Oo4eCf0zpm7iXdv3BPfe/xb8W/vO8vu69yvemD1oO6hx8MDj8Ifnft9/O+djxWP33WV/2Hwx7onTk9+/DPozzPdad2dT5mnvc8WPTd9vu3FyBetPfE9t18Wvnz3quK16evtb7zftL1Nffvg3dT3nPfVH5w/NH+M/nizt7C3VyFiRAAACgCZnQ082wbopANG5wDeePWeBwAg1LspoP4P8p9t9S4IAPACtgUByXOBmBZgQwtgPxfgtwDxAJKCQI4Y0X9pTnH2CA+1Fp8BWK97e59bAJxm4APT2/tufW/vhy0AdR1omaLeLwGArQ98owsAJ9unfrYo/hut3X80KW0+GQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAABrRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuNi1jMTQwIDc5LjE2MDQ1MSwgMjAxNy8wNS8wNi0wMTowODoyMSAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RFdnQ9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZUV2ZW50IyIgeG1sbnM6ZGM9Imh0dHA6Ly9wdXJsLm9yZy9kYy9lbGVtZW50cy8xLjEvIiB4bWxuczpwaG90b3Nob3A9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20vcGhvdG9zaG9wLzEuMC8iIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIiB4bXA6Q3JlYXRlRGF0ZT0iMjAxOS0wMS0yMVQxNTozMzo0MSswMzowMCIgeG1wOk1ldGFkYXRhRGF0ZT0iMjAyMC0wNC0yOVQyMjozODowNCswMzowMCIgeG1wOk1vZGlmeURhdGU9IjIwMjAtMDQtMjlUMjI6Mzg6MDQrMDM6MDAiIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6ZWE1YjE0NGQtNjczOS00YmYyLTg0ZmYtNmFkMjlkYTZmNTlkIiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJhZG9iZTpkb2NpZDpwaG90b3Nob3A6OGM0MWExZjUtMGE3NS1iNjRhLThlY2UtYTI0YjRlNjdlZmE3IiB4bXBNTTpPcmlnaW5hbERvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6NGU0ODQwM2UtNTYzNS00MmM4LTkxYzQtZjZlODIzMzk0MDg5IiBkYzpmb3JtYXQ9ImltYWdlL3BuZyIgcGhvdG9zaG9wOkNvbG9yTW9kZT0iMyIgcGhvdG9zaG9wOklDQ1Byb2ZpbGU9IkRpc3BsYXkiPiA8eG1wTU06SGlzdG9yeT4gPHJkZjpTZXE+IDxyZGY6bGkgc3RFdnQ6YWN0aW9uPSJjcmVhdGVkIiBzdEV2dDppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjRlNDg0MDNlLTU2MzUtNDJjOC05MWM0LWY2ZTgyMzM5NDA4OSIgc3RFdnQ6d2hlbj0iMjAxOS0wMS0yMVQxNTozMzo0MSswMzowMCIgc3RFdnQ6c29mdHdhcmVBZ2VudD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIi8+IDxyZGY6bGkgc3RFdnQ6YWN0aW9uPSJzYXZlZCIgc3RFdnQ6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo3MjliNmNjMy01Y2Y3LTQzOWUtYTA1YS1lOTNhN2FjYzg2OWEiIHN0RXZ0OndoZW49IjIwMTktMDEtMjFUMTU6MzM6NDErMDM6MDAiIHN0RXZ0OnNvZnR3YXJlQWdlbnQ9IkFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgc3RFdnQ6Y2hhbmdlZD0iLyIvPiA8cmRmOmxpIHN0RXZ0OmFjdGlvbj0ic2F2ZWQiIHN0RXZ0Omluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6ZWE1YjE0NGQtNjczOS00YmYyLTg0ZmYtNmFkMjlkYTZmNTlkIiBzdEV2dDp3aGVuPSIyMDIwLTA0LTI5VDIyOjM4OjA0KzAzOjAwIiBzdEV2dDpzb2Z0d2FyZUFnZW50PSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ0MgKE1hY2ludG9zaCkiIHN0RXZ0OmNoYW5nZWQ9Ii8iLz4gPC9yZGY6U2VxPiA8L3htcE1NOkhpc3Rvcnk+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+x4suaAAAA5FJREFUeJzt20uLHFUYxvHf1KgkKk4wMCEIUcGoMSAGyeBK8RLwsjFZ6CfwAuJ1bbI0++gmfgNduDOB6Ci6iYwKLtSxTSAmoHEGRm3BZBidlIszHXvavlR3ddWZrp4/NFRXV9V53rdP3d7LRJqmSuBa3Im7sBO3YBu2rP2+jD/wMy6ihh/xd9HCrinw2DvwKB7E/diDGzLu+xfm8TU+xywWCtBoooAZ8CyewZP++4fzsowTeB/vDemYGJ4DbsRLeAG3D+OAXTiH43gbl3IfLU3TvJ9X0zRdSMvn17Wxc+nPMwMewDHsz/0v5ONLvIIvBtk5GXDQN3FafOMJGk4Lmvqm3xlwHT7AU4MMVgIf4hBWsu7QjwN24lPhXr6RqeFh4XmiJ1kdcCvmMD24rlJZxAzO99owiwOm8T2259dVKku4R3BGR3o5YBJnFH9vL4pz2I3VThv0ugucNLrGE7Sf7LZBNwccxoGhyonDAcGWtnQ6Bfbi26IURWKvcC1bRycH1ITX1ypxRhub2p0Cz7fbsALsxoutK1tnwCTqsr+3jxqXMIV/GitaZ8Brqms8XC/YeJXWGbCEm0sUFIPfND3UNc+Ap1XfeIKNBxtfmh3wvwtEhXmusdA4BabwOyZiKSqZK8JMqDdmwOPGx3jCzH+isUAIX48bjxAcMCm8O48bM5icSNN0D74Rwl3jxAr2JULGZtyMJ9h8d4JdsZVEZFdidOJ8RTCdCFnacWVbgq2xVURk66CZoapwJcHl2CoispwIlRnjSj3RI3FQcRYTXIitIiIXEqEWJ3M2tUKs4IdEqMaajywmBvOoJULebC6ymBjMYbXxHDAbU0kkZtkMiV0NidVxKp6e0jkl2LwuKnw8jpYovNtY2EyMtPz4VrlaonC0+Uu75OifQg6tilzGTbokR1fxepmKSuYNTcYzXgUSZ4UagXV0CogcKlZLFA62W9nJAd/hSHFaSueIDjVPveoEP8JjRSgqkY91qXbLUih5FrcNV1Np/IQ75CiUXBX6ApaGp6k0lgTtHY0nW7/AgtD0NEqhs0VBc89Gq6xh8fO4T7g9bnRq2CdDpTj9dYxcxL1C99ZG5YSg8ZesO/SbGFkRukU61t5G5LCgra/4ZhWapr7Cy0pumrI24IxQeBjjArmwNvZ+AxrPaDdOviO02OZis3W2AAc02CFUYj0kX/P0Z/jECDVPt6Nd+/yU9e3zdRHa5/8FGLnMg5/e7DMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
      
var pattern = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
    
var width = 512,
    height = 512;

inits();
    
function inits(){

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - 1, 1, 1, - 1, 0, 1 );
scene.add(camera);

  
var points = [];
var colors = [];
    
var N = 32;  
for(var y = N/2; y <= height; y += N){
    for(var x = N/2; x <= width; x += N){
        var dx = -1.0 + x / width * 2;
        var dy = -1.0 + y / height * 2;
        points.push(new THREE.Vector2(dx, dy));
    }
}
    
buffer = {

    position: new Float32Array(points.length * 3),
    color: new Float32Array(points.length * 3),
    radius: new Float32Array(points.length * 1),

};
    
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    
    buffer.position[i * 3] = points[i].x;
    buffer.position[i * 3 + 1] = points[i].y;
    buffer.position[i * 3 + 2] = 0;
    
    buffer.radius[i] = N * 0.5;
    
    buffer.color[i * 3] = 1.0;
    buffer.color[i * 3 + 1] = 0.0;
    buffer.color[i * 3 + 2] = 1.0;
}
    
uniforms = { 
    
    blob: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(blob) },
    pattern: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(pattern) }
    
};

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    transparent: true
    
} );
    
material.extensions.fragDepth = true;
material.extensions.drawBuffers = true;

var cloud = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

cloud.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer.position, 3));
cloud.addAttribute('radius', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer.radius, 1));
cloud.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(buffer.color, 3));
    
var points = new THREE.Points(cloud, material);
points.dynamic = true;
points.frustumCulled = false;

scene.add(points);
    
animate();
    
}

function animate() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>

<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertexShader'>
uniform sampler2D blob;
uniform sampler2D pattern;
attribute float radius;
attribute vec3 color;

varying vec3 vColor;
varying vec2 pos;

void main() {

    vColor = color;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_PointSize = radius;
    pos = (position.xy + 1.0) / 2.0;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragmentShader'>
uniform sampler2D blob;
uniform sampler2D pattern;
varying vec3 vColor;
varying vec2 pos;

void main() {

    vec4 color = texture2D(pattern, vec2(pos.x, pos.y));
    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(blob, gl_PointCoord);
    if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.1) discard; 
}
</script>
```